# find file within a particular directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using this current find command:

```
find . -name "313958000002101817.pdf"
```

I am currently in a directory that looks similar to this:

```
/n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB
```

Within this directory, I have IDs so that my directory structure looks similar to this:

```
/n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB/1234
/n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB/1235
/n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB/1236
```

I know that the PDFs that I am looking for are in this job directory:

```
/n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB/"ID"/PDFs
```

Is there a way to throw a wildcard for a job directory in the middle of the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of per-job directories isn't so large that it won't fit on a command line, this is trivial:

```
find /n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB/*/PDFs -name "313958000002101817.pdf" -print
```

What we're doing here is instructing the shell to pass a list of job directories to `find`. That won't work beyond a point, though. Assuming that you're dealing with a larger set...

```
find /n01/data/adf/fp08_traffic/jobs/FB -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name PDFs \
  -exec sh -c 'exec find "$@" -name "313958000002101817.pdf" -print' _ {} +
```

The first `find` generates a list of `PDFs` directories. `-exec sh -c '...' _ {} +` then passes those directory names on the argument list of a shell (as many to each shell invocation as possible for efficiency), which then passes them in the appropriate location of a new `find` command per batch. (The shell is needed because `-exec ... {} +` only allows substitutions at the end of an argument list, not at any prior location, whereas `find` needs the list of directories to come before the list of predicates).

Comment: What's the reason for calling `exec find` in the `sh -c` argument? Saving a process?

Comment: @BenjaminW., right -- no point to a needless `fork()`. Some versions of `sh` may elide that already, but making it explicit ensures we get that behavior regardless.